# Registering 2 local notification simultaneously with same request identifier not overwriting

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I am creating one reminder with local notification in which I have to register one local notification with some identifier lets say X which should be fired at the defined interval with no repeat, and at the same time I want to register the same notification with same identifier after 10 minutes the first one gets fired.

In my case, if first notification gets fired and user doesn't take any action on it then after 10 minutes if same notification gets fired then in the notification center(tray) there should not be 2 notifications. Instead, only last notification should be there.

below is my code what I have done to accomplish this:

```
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.tutorial


    let notificationTrigger1 = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)

    let request1 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger1)

    center.add(request1, withCompletionHandler: {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("add NotificationRequest1 succeeded!")
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [Notification.Category.tutorial])
        }
    })


    let notificationTrigger2 = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60*10, repeats: true)

    let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger2)

    center.add(request2, withCompletionHandler: {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("add NotificationRequest2 succeeded!")
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [Notification.Category.tutorial])
        }
    })
```

Here in this code, the issue is the first notification doesn't get fired and only second notification gets fired after 10 min.

Comment: Are you in the main thread?

Comment: Yes I am in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing previously scheduled notifications two times:

```
if error == nil {
    print("add NotificationRequest2 succeeded!")
    //remove previous notifications
    center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [Notification.Category.tutorial]) 
}
```

You should setup both notifications when app goes idle in advance assuming user will not react - that's your only chance to setup both of them.

To remove second one when user takes action is to remove unwanted notification inside code that handles that action or take care of that logic when app becomes active.

Comment: Ok - But If I dont remove this then I will get 2 notifications on the center if no action is performed on the first one and app is idle.

Comment: I want only last one notification on the center when second one gets fired. The first one should be automatically removed when the second one gets fired.